# Passing from container of objects to container of an attribute of these objects

Tags: c++, boost

For example, given the code below and a single driver object I would like to obtain the std::set of skills_ids which contains the ids of skills that the driver has (or a vector if skills_ is an std::vector).

Is there an elegant/efficient way for doing that (not simply iterating on the skills container)?

```
class skill {
public:
    unsigned long id_;
    std::string name_;
};

class driver {
public:
    std::set<shared_ptr<skill> > skills_;
    // ---> how to elegantly get an std::set< unsigned int > skills_ids; 
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform), [`std::inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter) and a lambda.

```
std::set<unsigned int> skill_ids;

std::transform(skills_.begin(), skills_.end(), std::inserter(skill_ids, skill_ids.begin()), [](skill& s){return s.id_;})
```

Comment: Opinion based, but maybe usage of `std::transform` instead of `std::copy` would be more descriptive?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right. `std::copy` doesn't even take an `UnaryOperation` :) Thanks!